# Software RAID disapears after rebooting

Tags: server, 15.04, raid, mdadm

I'm currently trying to setup a media server and I'm having issues with my software RAID. It seems like once I reboot the server the RAID doesn't get assembled despite there being an entry in the config file.

**What I've tried**

I built the RAID using Webmin (mdadm GUI I think is what it's called), put a filesystem on the raid, added the RAID config to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` and added an entry in the `/etc/fstab` table. I mounted the RAID and everything seemed ok until I rebooted. Ubuntu would reboot into emergency mode and would only boot correctly once I removed the entry in the `fstab` file.

Once the server is booted with the `fstab` entry removed I can no longer see the raid (running `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose` says it can't find any RAID superblocks on any drives). My best guess is that the RAID isn't assembled and causes Ubuntu to fail to boot because the entry in `fstab` is incorrect.

I've tried this twice now with the same results. Any help on getting this to work would be greatly appreciated. Ideally I would like to recover the RAID I setup previously as it takes about 8 hours to initialize a new one.

**Specs**

- OS: Ubuntu Server 15.04
- OS HDD: Some 250GB HDD
- RAID HDDs: 3x WB 3TB Red

**mdadm.conf**

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Fri, 03 Jul 2015 18:56:47 -0600
# by mkconf $Id$
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=EmbyServer:0 UUID=a2a6dfab:c036097c:1f69bef0:63f3f469
```

**fstab**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=88022c97-726f-494b-b5d3-025f2de8dd99 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#Commented out so Ubuntu would boot correctly
#/dev/md0 /media ext4 defaults 1 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some messing around, it seems this issue was caused by the RAID not being setup on the partitions of the disk.

The RAID was created using the command:

`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata 1.2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd`

Creating partitions and changing it to:

`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata 1.2 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1`